# Understanding complex website architecture (reactjs,node, CDN, AWS S3, nginx)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-s3, architecture

Can somebody explain to me the architecture of [this website (link to a picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYvtq.png) ? I am struggling to understand the different elements in the front-end section as well as the fields on top, which seem to be related to AWS S3 and CDNs. The backend-section seems clear enough, although I don't understand the `memcache`. I also don't get why in the front end section an `nginx proxy` is needed or why it is there.

I am an absolute beginner, so it would be really helpful if somebody could just once talk me through how these things are connected.

[Source](https://ustwo.com/blog/open-sourcing-our-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcache is probably used to cache the results of frequent database queries.  It can also be used as a session database so that authenticated users' session work consistently across multiple servers, eliminating a need for server affinity (memcache is one of several ways of doing this).

The CDN on the left caches images in its edge locations as they are fetched from S3, which is where they are pushed by the WordPress part of the application.  The CDN isn't strictly necessary but improves down performance by caching frequently-requested objects closer to where the viewers are, and lowers transport costs somewhat.

The nginx proxy is an HTTP router that selectively routes certain path patterns to one group of servers and other paths to other groups of servers -- it appears that part of the site is powered by WordPress, and part of it node.js, and part of it is static react code that the browsers need to fetch, and this is one way of separating the paths behind a single hostname and routing them to different server clusters.  Other ways to do this (in AWS) are Application Load Balancer and CloudFront, either of which can route to a specific server based on the request path, e.g. `/assets/*` or `/css/*`.